# Parse XML element with same tag using Sax

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

Hi guys i have a problem when i try to parse a xml element with same tag

```
<question id="0">
<text> Who is the first President of the United States of America? </text>
<image> http://liisp.uncc.edu/~mshehab/api/figures/georgewashington.png </image>
<choices>
    <choice answer="true">George Washington</choice>
    <choice>Thomas Jefferson</choice>
    <choice>James Monroe</choice>
    <choice>John Adams</choice>
</choices>
</question>
```

I can parse all the others stuff but i can only parse the last "choice"

here is the part of the code for parsing

```
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            if(localName.equals("text")){
                question.setText(xmlInnerText.toString().trim());
            } else if(localName.equals("image")){
                question.setImageURL(xmlInnerText.toString().trim());
            } else if(localName.equals("choices")){
                if(localName.equals("choice")){
                question.setChoice(xmlInnerText.toString().trim());
                }
            } else if(localName.equals("question")){
                questions.add(question);
            } 
            xmlInnerText.setLength(0);
        }
```

Comment: Your logic seems incorrect. If localName equals "choices", how can it ever also equal "choice" in the child if statement?

Comment: well, all the choices are under "choices, dont i need another if for "choice" to get the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what is happening now is that you are setting the choice, but then you set it again (replacing it). So you only get the last.

You must add each choice to a List and then `question.setChoices(choices)` where `choices` is a List . (When you get a "choice" you do `choices.add(xmlInnetText.toString().trim());`

**Edit**: also as @rmlan said it doesn't seem you would ever get to "choice". You don't need to do an `if` inside the "choices" `if`. The "choice" `if` can be at the same level as the others `if`s. Aside this fact the answer above true: you need a List to save each "choice".

**Edit2**:

You need something like this:

```
(...)

} else if(localName.equals("choice")) {
    choices.add(setChoice(xmlInnerText.toString().trim());
} else if(localName.equals("choices")){
    question.setChoices(choices);
}                


(...)
```

Comment: @Samson I can only reply here: You don't need an if for "choice" just because "choice" is inside of "choices". You would need extra verification if you had "choice" under different tags, i.e: <choices> and inside <choice> and <someOtherTag> and inside <choice>.

Comment: so i only need to do "choices" to get the string inside "Choice"?

Comment: Nop. You need to do 
    `if(localName.equals("choice")){
         question.setChoice(xmlInnerText.toString().trim());
     }`
as well. But not inside the "choices" `if`.

Also, as I said you need to save each choice in a List.

**Edit:** I edited my answer with some code.